# Passing a function with two parameters into a function that accepts a function with one parameter as input in C

Tags: c, function-parameter

I am coding in C.  I would like to pass a function that accepts two parameters with one parameter set to a value into a function that accepts a function with one parameter as input.

```
void fTwoParameters( float a, float b ){
}

void outerFunction( void (*fOneParameter)(float) ){
}

void main( void ){
  // How can I do that?
  for( int i=1, i<1000, i++ ){
    // I would like to pass fTwoParameters into outerFunction with b set to the value of i
    outerFunction( /* Problem is Here */ )
  }
}
```

I think that this can be done with global variables.  Is there a way to do it without a global variable?

Comment: `void helper(float a) { fTwoParameters(a, 3.14159f); }`

Comment: @pmg Thank you for your reply.  My example was not complete enough.  I want to be able to pass in many different values for b.  Please see the edits above.

Comment: And you can't change the signature of `outerFunction`, perhaps because it is from an external lib? (I have a feeling that there could be a solution if you provided the real scenario, not a reduced example.)

Comment: Well, then you cannot. If the float value is between `0` and `1` (excluding `1` itself) and you have no accuracy issues... pass `i + value` (`1.0102`, `2.0102`, ..., `999.0102`)

Comment: @MOehm outerFunction is an optimization function called binary search.  It optimizes an objective function of one parameter.  I have an objective function of two parameters.  I want to iterate over the second parameter and for each value, perform binary search to determine the optimal first parameter.  That is, I want to do an exhaustive search over the second parameter.  Thoughts?

Comment: No, there's no way to do it without a global variable (or some other kind of global state). C does not support closures.

Comment: Aha, thanks for clarifying. I don't see any solution without using globals or without redesigning the interface. Why don't you want to use globals -- concurrency issues?

Comment: @MOehm I can use a global variable.  I just try to avoid them.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your best course of action is redesign the function so it take a proper "callback" (a function + data pointer pair) instead of a bare function pointer as argument(s). Eg. `struct cb { void (*f)(struct cb*, double); }; void outerFunc(struct cb *cb){ ... }; void your_func(struct cb *cb, double x){ ... }; struct { struct cb cb; double y; } my_cb = {{your_func}, 6.66 }; outerFunc(&my_cb.cb)` (That's just one of ways to do it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately standard C won’t help you much here. You *can* set a global variable though these tend to make the program harder to understand down the line.

The standard way of solving this issue is to make sure that any function `outer` that you define and which accepts a pointer to another function `inner`, accepts an argument which is just passed to `inner`. (Very often this argument will be `void*`, in particular in the case of libraries so that it can pass anything.)

```
int inner(int x, void* user_data) {
  int y = *((int*)user_data);
  return x * y;
}

int outer(int (*inner)(int, void*), void* user_data) {
  return inner(42, user_data);
}

int main(void) {
  int y = 17;
  return outer(&inner, &y);
}
```

If you are using GCC, you can use nested functions, but beware that these are a GNU extension and may not work with other compilers.

```
float twoParameters(float a, float b) {
  return a * b;
}

void main(void) {
  const float a = 42.0;

  float oneParameter(float b) {
    return twoParameters(a, b);
  }

  outerFunction(&oneParameter);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> outerFunction is an optimization function called binary search. It optimizes an objective function of one parameter. I have an objective function of two parameters. I want to iterate over the second parameter and for each value, perform binary search to determine the optimal first parameter. That is, I want to do an exhaustive search over the second parameter. Thoughts?

Making this clear since the beginning would have avoided any confusion.

**You cannot** (not even with a global variable). If you cannot change the code of `outerFunction` or `fTwoParameters` then you have to create a new different function by yourself.

---

**OLD ANSWER**

You can't. C does not allow passing a different type as the one defined in the function signature. Whatever you want to achieve with that, you will need to do it in a different way.

For example you could create a generic function with an additional argument to indicate the number of arguments (pass the function cast to `void (*)(void)` in this case):

```
void outerFunction(unsigned nargs, void (*funcptr)(void)) {
    if (nargs == 1) {
        void (*realfunc)(float) = (void (*)(float))funcptr;
        realfunc(1.0);
    } else if (nargs == 2) {
        void (*realfunc)(float, float) = (void (*)(float, float))funcptr;
        realfunc(1.0, 2.0);
    } /* ... */
}
```

You don't really need to pass the function though. You can just call it from another function (or `main`) with a whatever second parameter you want.

---

Addressing your edit, you can just do the following:

```
void outerFunction(void (*funcptr)(float, float), float b) {
    funcptr(1, b);
}

for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++){
    outerFunction(fTwoParameters, i);
}
```

Or even:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++){
    fTwoParameters(1, i);
}
```

There's no real need to pass any function pointer around. You should create a better example explaining what you're *really* trying to do and why that would make any sense, because from your current question, it really doesn't. This looks like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).